# WindowServer[185]: send_datagram_available_ping: pid 460 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out

Tags: php, console

I was using MAMP for PHP files with connection to an SQL database. After fixing the problem  [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280673/sqlstatehy0002002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-nodename-nor) it gave me an error 500 -

> "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8888/git/Way-of-life/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

So I checked the console and it said -

> "WindowServer[185]: send_datagram_available_ping: pid 460 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out."

Now, I know very little about the console so please tell me what that means.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***
Well I figured it out. Where it says "or configured incorrectly", that was the problem. My PHP read:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';port=8889;dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.);
```

It should have instead read:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';port=8889;dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Notice the difference of a "." at the very end. I have not figured one thing out. Can someone explain why this was causing the error in the first place?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the WindowServer? In my case, I'm not running MAMP that I'm aware of on my OSX system.

Comment: The WindowServer message is probably not connected to the MAMP problems. If you get the 'send_datagram_available_ping you can check what process caused this message with:  `ps -p 460` where 460 is the pid that's mentioned in the log message.